# How to get badge announces: “Share a link to a question later visited by 25 unique IP addresses”

Tags: support, badges

How do badges work? I have noticed that [here](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=General&filter=all) there are a lot of badges, that are not mentioned in [next badge]. In particular `announces`: “Share a link to a question later visited by 25 unique IP addresses”. In my question on goto, it has over 7000 views, at least some come from a link I made on another site (using the share link).

I would have thought that 25 would come from unique IP addresses.

Is there a way to see progress on this badge? I know I can see progress on some badges, in the users area.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of guesses.

1) Your shared link is in ASCII, not with a  tag, so it's not clickable. I shared an anonymous link to the same question later in the thread, so that may have taken some views. Often when I see a link as text, I may just take the domain name and enter a site there.

2) I feel these badges are awarded during a batch run, rather than in real time. So your 'announcer' may come tomorrow. I don't remember getting any particularly quickly (but have picked up a few over time).

Answer (score 1):

> There is no way to see progress on this badge.

#### How it tracks?

When you share a link from the share option, the link will contain your user id at the end.

For your question, my share id is

```
https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/q/320/97
                                                 ^^  -- User id
```

Using that id, Stack Exchange determine whether the traffic is came from a link you've shared or not. To get the badge Announcer, the link you have shared to a single question must be visited from more than 25 Unique IP addresses.

If you're sure that 25 people visited using your link, you have to wait for some time to get the badge awarded because it is not immediate. It is a process that award the badges.